# Does the riff in *Shake Your Body* (The Jacksons) sound the same as the one in "Golden Years" (Bowie)?

Tags: sample

The bass line from **Shake Your Body (Down to the Ground)** sounds the same as the sung hook "Run for the shadows" from the middle of **Golden Years**.  Should Bowie get a writing credit for the Jacksons song?

[David Bowie - Golden Years](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUuRGRcY9O0&feature=youtu.be&t=115)
[The Jacksons - Shake Your Body (Down to the Ground)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAZA6oNEWZg&feature=youtu.be&t=10)

Answer (score 3):

They do sound similar! Writing credit would be too much. After all its just a bassline which sounds similar, not the same.